# LD_PRELOAD malloc to shm_open

Tags: malloc, shared-memory, dynamic-linking, ld-preload, librt

I'm trying to intercept `malloc` call using `LD_PRELOAD`. I want to move all memory allocation to shared memory by changing `malloc` to `shm_open` followed by `mmap`. How can I do it?

LD_PRELOAD of `malloc` works fine. I can intercept every `malloc` call. However, calling `shm_open` in intercepted `malloc` fails because `shm_open` requires linking of `librt` which links to `libdl` that `dlsym` in LD_PRELOAD requires. There is a recursive interposition. I thought about creating a static library of wrapped shared memory allocation. Then call it from intercepted `malloc`. But `librt` cannot be linked dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it?

In general, you can't.

If you want to interpose low-level functions like `malloc`, your best bet is to only use lower-level direct system calls.

Using anything higher-level, such as `shm_open`, is bound to run into trouble sooner of later. Even if `shm_open` didn't use `librt` and `dlopen` today, there is nothing that prevents it doing so tomorrow (and breaking your carefully constructed house of cards).

Besides the obvious direct recursion problems, there may also be "order of initialization" problems (e.g. `shm_open` may require that `malloc` and `librt` have initialized, which isn't guaranteed when the very first `malloc` is called).

Comment: I'm trying to move it to memory mapped file-based design. Do you see the same concern as the shared memory one.